# Qualtrics Javascript: Get all responses and survey text

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm hoping to get a Qualtrics respondant's entire set of responses to a survey along with the question text. This needs to be via javascript in the question.

I found `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.QuestionInfo`, which gets all the question text on the page, but I can't find an object that has all the user responses, and I can't find a whole-survey version of `QuestionInfo`.

I don't need *every* user's responses, just the *current* user's. (I'm doing some processing on it.)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Qualtrics API to retrieve a survey response: https://api.qualtrics.com/1179a68b7183c-retrieve-a-survey-response

Comment: Thanks for the link! That could work. It looks like this would require an API key, though - would I end up exposing the API key to people who are taking the survey? (Assuming they're savvy enough to examine the javascript.)

Comment: Not sure what 'processing' you are doing, but typically it would be done by a webservice triggered from a Qualtrics 'Workflow' upon survey completion and that webservice would do the API call. I think the survey has to be recorded before you can retrieve it with the API. Otherwise, it is 'in-progress'. In summary, the API call would be done by the server and not client based.